# Publishing JSON Data in Django templates

Tags: python, json, django

I am new to Django and Python so question might appear silly at first but after various attempts I am failing to get my desired result.

The json data looks like this

```
{
  "name":"Oliver",
   "status": "single"
  "age":"22",
  "About":{ "hobbies" : ["cricket","football","chess"], "dob":"1st_January_2000"}
}
```

I need to display all the information in a django template based table. I am comfortable in handling basic json with templates but cant frame a template for this one.

Comment: How the output table should looks like?

Comment: Table headers will be name ,status ,age,hobbies and dob

Comment: But in your json data, value of status is not available?

Comment: Made the edit.. Updated json data

Answer (score 0):

From your `json data`, Assuming table header are Name, Age, Status, Hobbies and DOB

Render json data to your template by passing it in in `view.py`

then to display table information from json data in your template, you can use the below code

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>age</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th>Status</th> 
    <th>Hobbies</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>{{td_data.name}}</td>
    <td>{{td_data.age}}</td>
    <td>{{td_data.status}}</td>
    <td>{{td_data.About.dob}}</td>
    <td>{{td_data.About.hobbies}}</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Note: In this code I have assigned the given `json data` to variable `td_data` which is rendered from `view.py`

hope it will help you :)